# Loading a File from Google Bucket into PyDub AudioSegment

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, pydub

I have been trying for a while to load a .mp3 file which exists in a Google Bucket into Pydub. Here is my code

```
f = io.BytesIO()
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket_name="my-bucket"
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name) 
blob = bucket.blob(file_path)
blob.download_to_file(f)

currentAudio=AudioSegment.from_mp3(f)
```

Here is the Path to the File 
https://storage.cloud.google.com/written-audio-files/10530c70-52af-4ed7-a2ad-146738141b41.mp3

So this file exists and is also downloaded correctly. When the last line

```
currentAudio=AudioSegment.from_mp3(f)
```

is executed, I get an FFMPEG error.

```
pydub.exceptions.CouldntDecodeError: Decoding failed. ffmpeg returned error code: 1

Output from ffmpeg/avlib:

b'ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers\n  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)\n  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared\n  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100\n  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100\n  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100\n  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100\n  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100\n  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0\n  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100\n  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100\n  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100\n[mp3 @ 0x556a1d4c7820] Failed to read frame size: Could not seek to 1026.\npipe:: Invalid argument\n'
```

To, me it appears that when a BytesIO object is given to the function `from_mp3`, it expects a Physical File versus an In Memory BytesIO object.

I am executing this on a Google Cloud function , where I probably will not have any local storage. Plus, it will be time consuming to save the file, and then reload the file from /tmp

Saving to local filesystem and reopening the file works as expected on my local computer where I am currently testing the program.
How do we circumvent the issue?

** Update ** 
Passing the downloaded file to ffmpeg yields the following output

```
ffmpeg -i 10530c70-52af-4ed7-a2ad-146738141b41.mp3 -hide_banner
[mp3 @ 0x561b77222760] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from '10530c70-52af-4ed7-a2ad-146738141b41.mp3':
  Duration: 00:00:02.09, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, s16p, 32 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your file on the tmp directory and then provide the Path to AudioSegment().

```
tmpdir=tempfile.gettempdir() # prints the current temporary directory
tempFilePath=tmpdir+"/"+file_path
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket_name="my-bucket"
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)         
blob = bucket.blob(file_path)   
blob.download_to_filename(tempFilePath)     
currentAudio=AudioSegment.from_file(tempFilePath, format="mp3")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's something wrong with your MP3 file, I can't play it and FFMPEG is confused about what file type it is:

```
$ ffmpeg -i 10530c70-52af-4ed7-a2ad-146738141b41.mp3 -hide_banner
[mp3 @ 0x7fa661000000] Format mp3 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[mp3 @ 0x7fa661000000] Failed to read frame size: Could not seek to 58401.
10530c70-52af-4ed7-a2ad-146738141b41.mp3: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Let me see what the output of the command is for other mp3 files generated and I will report the findings. Is the .mp3 broken enough to trouble ffmpeg, but not broken enough to play seamlessly in VLC?

Comment: I can't even play it in VLC.

Comment: I could play it in VLC Media Player, and have added output of ffmpeg in the original question. FWIW, the mp3 has been generated using Google Text to Speech. The audio says "All you get is three shots" Here is another file generated in the same manner which exhibits this behaviour https://storage.cloud.google.com/written_audio_local/track_text_2fbfa77e-4e37-409f-83a6-1d22331be85d.mp3?folder&organizationId&_ga=2.199448686.-1193043774.1571393819&_gac=1.116866292.1571729776.Cj0KCQjw0brtBRDOARIsANMDykYcdMO9KaCGVtrm1lAgXdIhZGKBU3hBPho0DPa4s3m-3QG9-BnAVKYaAugYEALw_wcB